# How to parse Json Array with gson in android

Tags: android, json, gson

I am developing android application and I am using gson for parsing json response.
My json responce looks like

```
[{"customerid":"abc","customername":"abc","location":null}

,{"customerid":"xyz","customername":"xyz","location":null}]
```

And class for parsing this response looks like :

```
public class CustomerInfo 
{   
    @SerializedName("customerid")
    public String customerid;

    @SerializedName("customername")
    public String customername;

    @SerializedName("location")
    public String location;

    public CustomerInfo()
    {}
}
```

I tried it in following way:

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  List<CustomerInfo> customers = (List<CustomerInfo>)gson.fromJson(result,CustomerInfo.class);
```

But its not working for me. How to do this. Need Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First you create getters and setters for all your variables inside class CustomerInfo i.e. for customerid, customername & location, then you can parse JSON using below code snippet:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonData gsonData = gson.fromJson(response, CustomerInfo.class);
for (int j = 0; j < gsonData.getCount(); j++) 
{
    String customerid = gsonData.get(j).getCustomerId();
    String customername = gsonData.get(j).getCustomerName();
    String location = gsonData.get(j).getLocation();
}
```

Comment: JsonData gsonData = gson.fromJson ??!!!

Comment: JsonData gsonData = gson.fromJson(response, CustomerInfo.class);  // response is in string and CustomerInfo.class is the class to which json is parsed